# Join two select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could somebody please, give me some advice on how to join the following two select statements:

```
SELECT TOP 200 * 
FROM dbo.Creation_LimitsAndExclusions WITH (nolock) 
WHERE LeagueCodeID = 37
```

and

```
select * 
from dbo.Creation_Markets with (nolock) 
where ClassID = 9 and IsParentMatch = 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: to make a join you have to use a column who is in both table

Comment: Using *Derived Tables* or *CommonTable Expressions*?

Comment: Welcome to SO Bet, it is always recommended for the person who is asking SQL questions to provide some sample data to view.

Comment: @dnoeth how about neither?

Comment: You can also use UNION if you want to display same number and type of columns and there is no common column in both tables. Please be more specific.

Comment: You might also look at this article for some more advice. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Yeah, wrong question. These are tables with meaning. What do they have in common? How can you make relationally the tables fit? Is it a 1 to 1 relationship or 1 to many? Anyways, it is evident the op has never heard of relational databases and ANSI JOIN syntax, let alone read actual documentation like MSDN (for SQL Server) that makes sense of the operations. Expect this question to not survive long.

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea what the key is, but if the key was CreationID in both tables a join would look like this:

```
SELECT TOP 200 * 
FROM dbo.Creation_LimitsAndExclusions WITH (nolock) 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Creation_Markets ON Creation_LimitsAndExclusions.CreationID = Creation_Markets.CreationID 
WHERE Creation_LimitsAndExclusions.LeagueCodeID = 37
  AND Creation_Markets.ClassID = 9 and Creation_Markets.IsParentMatch = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Also don't know what the key is but I would add a cm.creationId IS NOT NULL condition in the where clause to ensure that we aren't taking rows from Creation_LimitsAndExclusions that are not matched

```
SELECT TOP 200 * 
FROM dbo.Creation_LimitsAndExclusions cle WITH (nolock) 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Creation_Markets cm
    ON cle.CreationID = cm.CreationID 
WHERE cle.LeagueCodeID = 37
    AND cm.ClassID = 9 
    AND cm.IsParentMatch = 1
    AND cm.creationID IS NOT NULL
```